# Docked floating window into floating window in AvalonDock

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, avalondock

I'm using AvalanDock 2.0

Is the any way to docked floating window to another floating window as aditional tab? 
Result must be something like this:

[image]

I'm sorry about my English.

Comment: I use AvalonDock myself in a project, and tab dock on floating window works fine for me.

Comment: Do you mean that you can drag floating window on another and it docked as tab? Can you provide some sample please?

Comment: Check out this tutorial. [AvalonDock 2.0 Tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/483507/AvalonDock-Tutorial-Part-Adding-a-Tool-Windo). In the download sample project (v02) i can drag a tab onto a floating window and it will dock into the position i choose.

Comment: Thanks to you, that's all I need!

Comment: Arh, sorry.. Was investigating a little. Anchorables can be docked into floating anchorables, but documents can not. I'm trying to find out why, and if the library can be modified to support this.

Comment: After looking over the source code of, and experimenting with the AvalonDock 2.0 library, it is simply not a feature to dock a document into a floating document pane. I've tried to see if i could modify the source code, but it's going to take some extensive modification. However, the source code I was looking at was from the original creator (https://avalondock.codeplex.com/). Xceed has taken over the project now. Maybe they have added the feature (Take a look: [Extended WPF Toolkit™](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/))

Comment: Sorry, Could not resist, so i checked.. No they have not. :-(

Comment: @Nautious - Thank you very much for the answers and spend time. I'll try to digging into AvalonDock.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AvalonDock uses two concepts: Documents and Anchorables.

Using Visual Studio as a reference: Documents are the open files, and anchorables are the tool windows, such as *Solution Explorer*, *Properties*, *Toolbox* etc.

AvalonDock currently **only** supports docking of anchorables into floating anchorables, **not** docking of documents into floating documents.

If you need this feature you have two options:

1. Request new feature by the development team of AvalonDock in the [Forums](http://xceed.com/CS/forums/default.aspx)
2. Download the [SourceCode](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest) and try to implement the feature yourself.

Sorry to be the bearer of bad news.